# How to do delete rows based on indexed column in cassandra

Tags: kundera, cassandra-2.1

Current Approach that i am using for deleting rows based on indexed column

1. Select query with a limit 100.
2. If there are rows Delete all the fetched rows one by one.
3. Flush the entity Manager.
4. Go to step 1.

Using cassandra 2.1.8 and kundera-cassandra-ds-driver for fetching rows from cassandra.

Is there any way to fire a delete query from Kundera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
Query findQuery = entityManager.createQuery("Delete from PersonCassandra p where p.age = 10",
            PersonCassandra.class);
findQuery.setMaxResults(5000);
findQuery.executeUpdate();
```

**PS**: Cassandra does not allow deleting rows based on non-primary keys, Kundera handles this internally in a similar way that you are doing.

Comment: Does the query end up deleting only 5000 rows??

Comment: @Prabhath Yes.. if you do not specify any limit, it will delete 100 rows by default.